# Creating a link through multiple isset parameters

Tags: php, html

In my php project, to create a link or a query my code reads multiple isset parameters. For example I have the following isset parameters.

- Client_type
- Invoice_type
- Agent_Id
- Delivery_type

But all of them isn't set always. 
Let's say user sets 3 out fo 4 as following

- Client_type
- Invoice_type
- Delivery_type

and I must create a phrase in combination of those 3 parameters to use it in my link like :

```
$link_phrase = "client_type=5&invoice_type=4&delivery_type=6";
```

and another phrase for my query

```
$query_phrase = " where client_type=5 and invoice_type=4 and delivery_type=6"
```

How I can do that by taking in consideration only isset parameters?

Thanks

Comment: Have you got any code that tries to do this, it would give us a better understanding of what yo are actually asking

Answer (score 0):

First, check if the params are set. If so, add them to an array with. Afterwards implode the array with whatever delimiter you need.
I'd suggest something like that:

```php
$param_vals = array();

// check if paramter is set
if (isset($_POST['Client_type'])){
    // if so, add the entry to the array
    $param_vals[] = 'client_type=' . $_POST['Client_type'];
}
if (isset($_POST['Invoice_type'])){
    $param_vals[] = 'invoice_type=' . $_POST['Invoice_type'];
}

// ... other params

$link_phrase = implode('&', $link_params);
$query_phrase = " where " . implode('and', $link_params);
```

This can be simplified though to something like that:

```php
$params = array('Client_type', 'Invoice_type' /* any further params */);

foreach ($params as $param){
    if (isset($_POST[$param])){
        $param_vals[] = strtolower($param) . '=' . $_POST[$param];
    }
}

$link_phrase = implode('&', $link_params);
$query_phrase = " where " . implode(' and', $link_params);
```

As a side note, please validate the input coming from the `$_POST` variable. Also have a look at prepared statements, as for security reasons. For the sake of the example I just kept it short.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Let's In array I sets value of 3 out of 4 as following. I make Agent_Id value is null

```
$array = array("Client_type" => 5,
"Invoice_type" => 4,
"Agent_Id" => "",
"Delivery_type" => 6);
```

2 - using [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) retrun the  set elements from array

```
//array - can be your post data
    $set_item = array_filter($array, function($array){
        if($array != ''){
            return $array;
        }
    });
```

3 - and at last use [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) — Generate URL-encoded query string

```
$link_phrase = http_build_query($set_item);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/mRrM7)